# Randomized binary search algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

The algorithm below is supposed to be a variation of the binary search where instead of picking the middle a random index is chosen and compared. The algorithm is asymptotically worse but it was just a task. The algorithm considers the case when the element at random index i is equal to the searching value in which case it returns true, and the second case when the element at index i is greater than the search value, in which case we recursively call the search on a input n of i - 1. And if the element is always greater than or equal to the searching value then the algorithm works fine.

However what happens when the element at randomized index is less than the search value? Intuitively I thought the input n should increase by i + 1 and even with checking if n becomes larger than the array size, I seem to be getting stackoverflows..

```
public static boolean search(int[] keys, int value, int n) {
    if(n <= 0 || n > keys.length) 
        return false;
    else {
        Random random =   new Random();
        int i       =   random.nextInt(n);

        if(keys[i] == value) 
            return true;
        else if(keys[i] > value) 
            return search(keys, value, i - 1);
        else 
            return search(keys, value, i + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: is your `keys[]` 1-indexed? If not (and I feel it is not), change your `if` condition to `if(n < 0 || n >= keys.length)`

Comment: I just edited your code to post the idea in the answer. It should work now.

Comment: I am not using n in the indexes, it is used as the bound for the random so if there are no elements (n = 0) then the element doesn't exist in the array. I am also passing n as keys.length so having if(n >= keys.length) will always return false.

Comment: Lets say random return `1` and value equals keys[0], then you are passing 0 to next recursive call. It will return false then. And if that is your assumption (for n), in any case, you are searching the lower part of the array from index 0 to (i-1) or (i+1) and never the second part. So, it is wrong there as well.

Comment: I think initializing a new `Random` on every call of the method is bad practice. A single `Random` instance should be reused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fundamentally wrong (I think). According to what you say (the conditions in your problem statement), this should be the code:

```
public static boolean search(int[] keys, int value, int l, int r)
{
    if(l < 0 || r >= keys.length || l>r) return false;
    else
    {
        Random random =   new Random();
        int i       =   l + random.nextInt(r-l);

        if(keys[i] == value) return true;
        else if(keys[i] > value) return search(keys, value, l, i - 1);
        else return search(keys, value, i + 1, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove all `else`-s, they are useless here since `if`-s end with `return`.

Comment: Yes, true that. I just copied and pasted his code and did minimum edit to get to correct answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

See this part of your code,

```
 else if(keys[i] > value) 
     return search(keys, value, i - 1); //Line1
 else 
     return search(keys, value, i + 1); //Line2
```

You are searching in the same part of the array in both case.

`Line1` searches for the `value` in the array from `0` to `i - 1`.
`Line2` searches for the `value` in the array from `0` to `i + 1`.

What you should have done is,

`Line1` should search for the `value` in the array from `0` to `i - 1`.
`Line2` should search for the `value` in the array from `i + 1` to end of array.